# Cannot upload any file or image in SharePoint 2013 with Outbound rules in URL Rewrite

Tags: sharepoint-server, url-rewriting

I had added a Outbound rule in IIS and i cannot upload any file or image to document library. it's show error below

http://server/site/_layouts/15/UploadEx.aspx?List=%7b65AB3E28-245D-40F6-8A50-F44FC56ACE62%7d&RootFolder=&IsDlg=1 net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

[image: Url rewrite outbound rule]

anyone can help me!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

May be this link will help but check with the rules in IIS

[Part 1](https://myspworld.wordpress.com/2012/07/05/url-rewriting-part-1-the-basics/)

[Part 2](https://myspworld.wordpress.com/2012/10/03/url-rewriting-part-2-outbound-rule/)

**URL Rewriting links** will give an clear idea about Outbound rules.